# Android default colors theme

Tags: android, colors, themes, background-color

I'm currently having the following problem. I changed the default style of the application, my styles.xml looks like this

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
    <item name="android:editTextColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/menu_spinner</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/menu_spinner</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>


<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:editTextColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/App_EditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/menu_spinner</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/menu_spinner</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="App_EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>


<style name="LoginFormContainer" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:padding">16dp</item>
</style>

<style name="menu_spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>

<style name="spinner_style" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_bg</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.CheckBox" parent="Widget.Holo.CompoundButton.CheckBox" />

<style name="Widget.Holo.CompoundButton.CheckBox" parent="Widget.Holo.CompoundButton.CheckBox" />
```

However, all my dialogs show a darker background, I don't understand why they do not have white background, as I've defined the properties windowbackground and colorbackground by default as white. Here's how a progressdialog looks like by default:

[image]

In my AndroidManifest, the theme is "AppTheme":

```
<application
        android:name="com.activeandroid.app.Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icono_grande"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
....
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the theme for Dialog Specific, you could try something like this:

```
<!-- Makes a "light" equivalent of Theme.Dialog -->
<style name="dialog_light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="@android:background">@android:color/background_light</item>
    <!-- Whatever you want to add here -->  
</style>
```

If it is App wide, then something like this should do:

```
<!-- Makes a "light" equivalent of Theme.Dialog -->
<style name="popup_theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/back_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/back_color</item>
    <!-- Whatever you want to add here --> 
</style>
```

Comment: Problem is, as you can see I've already defined the colorbackground and windowbackground as white, however it's still not working :/

Comment: Did you try using this theme I specified rather than what you have? Because the theme I defined is supposed to be light so its GUI would be white or light colored

Comment: I'm adding the progress dialog programatically, like this:

groupsDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        groupsDialog.setMessage("Por favor espera...");
        groupsDialog.setCancelable(false);
        groupsDialog.setMax(100);
        groupsDialog.setProgressNumberFormat(null);
        groupsDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

What should I edit? The Styles.xml or how I build my progress dialog?

Comment: ProgressDialog groupsDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity, R.styles.dialog_light);

Comment: But is there a way to set this by default? It feels wrong to have to define white as background color each time i make a new progressdialog :/ thats what I'm trying to avoid